# Is there a way in C for the next node in a linked list be NULL by default?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, null

Is there a way in c for us to create a linked list struct where the next node value be NUll by default like in java we can do

```
class Node{
  int data;
  Node next
  Node(int d){
    data=d;
    next=NULL;
  }
}
```

here the next value is by default initialised to NULL is there any way to do this in c.

i dont want to do it in the main function so that code for creating a linked list will be smaller

Comment: you need to use pointers to the next node to do what you want. Try ``` Node* next = null ``` then when you created a new Node, you assign it's address to the pointer next = &newNode

Comment: The Java code you’ve shown uses a constructor. You can do the same in C by creating a function `Node *make_node(int d)`.

Comment: You cannot do that automatically. You need to call a "constructor"-like function or assign manually.

Comment: Another option is to use an initializer like `struct node n = { 0 };`

Comment: `calloc` the new node.